# Use gcc in mac instead of clang

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang

I have a mac with Ventura 13.5.1 (intel proc). I need to usc gcc instead of clang in mac, how i can do it?

Now i have smth like this on my mac:

```bash
λ ~/ gcc -v
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

λ /usr/bin/ gcc -v
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Here is the code, which will compile fine. But on linux with gcc it will raise float-conversion error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ERROR_OK 0
#define ERROR_IO 1
#define ERROR_RANGE 2
#define EPSILON 0.00001
 
int are_points_collinear(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3)
{
    return fabs((y3 - y2) * (x2 - x1) - (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x2)) < EPSILON;
}
 
float area(float x_a, float y_a, float x_b, float y_b, float x_c, float y_c)
{
    double s;
    s = 0.5 * fabs((x_b - x_a) * (y_c - y_a) - (x_c - x_a) * (y_b - y_a));
    return s;
}
 
int main(void)
{
    double x_a, y_a, x_b, y_b, x_c, y_c;
    double s;
 
    printf("Enter coordinates of point A (x, y): ");
    if (scanf("%lf %lf", &x_a, &y_a) != 2)
        return ERROR_IO;
 
    printf("Enter coordinates of point B (x, y): ");
    if (scanf("%lf %lf", &x_b, &y_b) != 2)
        return ERROR_IO;
 
    printf("Enter coordinates of point C (x, y): ");
    if (scanf("%lf %lf", &x_c, &y_c) != 2)
        return ERROR_IO;
 
    if (are_points_collinear(x_a, y_a, x_b, y_b, x_c, y_c))
        return ERROR_RANGE;
 
    s = area(x_a, y_a, x_b, y_b, x_c, y_c);
    printf("S = %lf\n", s);
 
    return ERROR_OK;
}
```

I compile with

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic -Wfloat-equal -Wfloat-conversion -Wextra -o app.exe main.c -lm
```

Comment: What's your _real_ problem? (That is to say, what is the clang-provided gcc compatibility wrapper doing wrong that makes you think you need real gcc?)

Comment: @Charles Duffy
Glad u asked. In my uni our testing system using gcc and compile prog with this command
`gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic -Wfloat-equal -Wfloat-conversion -Wextra -o app.exe main.c -lm`

This [prog](https://pastebin.com/2SSwC6r8) will compile fine

But on linux with gcc it will raise float-conversion error

Comment: Install gcc with homebrew. Fix aliases/symlinks to point to it.

Comment: Aside: why are you freely mixing `float` and `double` in the code? Is that what causes the objection? There will be constant conversion between those two types. The two functions should have `double` arguments to match everything else. Anyway never use `float` without a clear reason why you cannot use `double`, the natural floating point type in C. Also I see you want to compile with C99. Is your Uni stuck in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Wfloat-conversion` option gives a warning if you convert a `double` to a `float` due to a possible loss of precision, and `-Werror` converts all warnings to errors.  This warning or error is being triggered because your functions accept `float` arguments but you're passing in `double` arguments.

You typically shouldn't use `float` instead of `double` unless you have a specific reason for doing so, so change all `float` declarations to `double`.

```
int are_points_collinear(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
{
    return fabs((y3 - y2) * (x2 - x1) - (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x2)) < EPSILON;
}
 
double area(double x_a, double y_a, double x_b, double y_b, double x_c, double y_c)
{
    double s;
    s = 0.5 * fabs((x_b - x_a) * (y_c - y_a) - (x_c - x_a) * (y_b - y_a));
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I understand my mistake, my problem is not about code. My problem is about using gcc on mac. Try to compile my programm on clang with `-Wfloat-conversion` and `-Werror` u will get a working file. But try to use normal gcc (linux, win) and u will recive error.

Comment: @Nikolay No, you do have a code problem.  clang is just treating it differently than gcc is.  You need to fix your code.